# Extract substring of string if position is known

Tags: string, bash

first, I need to extract the substring by a known position in the file.txt
`file.txt` in bash, but starting from the second line

```
>header
cgatgcgctctgtgcgtgcgtgcg
```

so let's assume I want position `10` from the second line, the output should be:

```
c
```

second, I want to include the surrounding `±5` characters, resulting in

```
gcgctctgtgc
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I need X" and "I want X" are not (programming) questions.

Comment: @melpomene you are funny! First you post the only correct answer, then you complain for the question not being good enough. I think this is a legitimate question (how to do this in bash?), only lacking to show some effort. More funny, the OP accepted an answer in `awk`. Ah ah... at least, you got two upvotes!

Comment: I simply LOVE awk :D and it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

To get the character at position 10, 1-indexed:

```
awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0, 10, 1)}'
```

- `NR==2` is checking if the record is second, if so the statements inside `{}` would be executed
- `substr($0, 10, 1)` will extract 1 character starting from position 10 from field `$0` (the whole record) i.e. only the 10-th character will be extracted. The format for `substr()` is `substr(field, offset, length)`.

Similarly, to get ±5 characters around 10-th:

```
awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0, (10-5), 11)}'
```

`(10-5)` instead of `5` is just to give you the idea of the stuffs.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                      
>header
cgatgcgctctgtgcgtgcgtgcg

% awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0, 10, 1)}' file.txt     
c

% awk 'NR==2 {print substr($0, (10-5), 11)}' file.txt
gcgctctgtgc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{ read -r; read -r; echo "${REPLY:9:1}"; echo "${REPLY:4:11}"; } < file.txt
```

Output:

```
c
gcgctctgtgc
```

The `${parameter:offset:length}` syntax for substrings is explained in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

The `read` command is explained in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read.

Input redirection: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections.

Comment: @linuxfan OP didn't ask for an explanation, only code ("I need to do X in bash"), and most of the other answers don't explain anything either (notable exception: the awk one, but that one doesn't use bash).

Comment: Almost no one asks for explanation. But for future readers who might have a slightly different problem, the explanation is of great value.

Comment: So you think that every OP should ask explicitely for an explanation? I don't. Anyway, you are the only one who did respect the tag `bash`. But an explanation is useful to everyone happens to stumble on this question+answer.

Comment: @linuxfan No, I think every OP should explicitly ask a question. "I want X" or "I need X" aren't questions. Preferably questions should also include at least some effort to solve the problem (e.g. looking at the bash manual). This question should be closed as off-topic IMHO.

Comment: @linuxfan I try myself to do some research and find an explanation after a solution has been given; @melpomene nice way, when I am using it with a variable as part of a bigger script I am using it like this: `[...]${REPLY:($var-1):1}[...]`

Answer (score 1):

use sed and cut:

```
sed  -n '2p' file|cut -c 5-15
```

sed for access 2nd line and cut for print desired characters